# Getting the current instance of the PApplet in Processing

Tags: java, processing

A lot of Processing libraries need the user to pass a PApplet object for the libraries class to operate on.
The question is: Is it possible to create a static method `PAppletFinder.find()` to fetch the all PApplet instances?
(Link to the thread in the Processing Forum: https://discourse.processing.org/t/get-the-current-instance-of-papplet-from-a-library/36925/28)

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible! Processing has two weakpoints one can exploit!
Here is the code that works in Processing 4 & 3:

```java
import processing.awt.*;
import processing.opengl.*;
import processing.core.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

import sun.misc.*;
/**This class finds the active PApplet (Processing program)
 @author NumericPrime*/
public class PAppletFinder {
  /**Unsafe instance used*/
  public static Unsafe unsafe=null;
  /**Unsafe Field offset*/
  public static long fieldIndex=0;
  /**Target field of the thread*/
  public static Field threadTargField=null;
  /**Here the three Fields unsafe,fieldIndex, threadTargField are initalized*/
  static {
    try {
      Field f2=Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
      f2.setAccessible(true);
      unsafe=(Unsafe) f2.get(null);
      //System.out.println("Unsafe instance: "+unsafe.toString());
      threadTargField=Thread.class.getDeclaredField("target");
      fieldIndex=unsafe.objectFieldOffset(threadTargField);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  /**Getter-Method used to detect all PApplets. If the detection hasn't run yet this method will run it.
   @param refresh if true: redetects all PApplets
   @return all detected PApplets*/
  public static PApplet[] getPApplets(boolean refresh) {
    int allfpSize=0;
    if (refresh) allFoundPapplets.clear();
    if ((allfpSize=allFoundPapplets.size())==0) findAll();
    return allFoundPapplets.toArray(new PApplet[allfpSize]);
  }
  /**All results will be saved here*/
  public static java.util.List<PApplet> allFoundPapplets=new LinkedList<PApplet>();
  /**This class takes the contents of the window and pieces together the PApplet
   * @return PApplet of the current sketch.
   * @param c contents of the Processing window (must be a SmoothCanvas)*/
  public static void get(Component c) {
    //System.out.println("Processing Window content");
    PSurfaceAWT.SmoothCanvas sc=(PSurfaceAWT.SmoothCanvas) c;
    try {
      //gets the PSurface for the PApplet
      PSurfaceAWT psa=(PSurfaceAWT) get(sc, "this$0", sc.getClass());
      //gets the PApplet
      PApplet prg=(PApplet) get((PSurfaceNone)psa, "sketch", PSurfaceNone.class);
      allFoundPapplets.add(prg);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      //System.err.println("Something went wrong");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  /**This method tries to detect all PApplet used*/
  public static void findAll() {
    findFromWindow();
    fromThreads();
    //System.out.println("Detection done");
  }

  /**This looks out for processing-windows and gives the contents of the right one to the get method*/
  public static void findFromWindow() {
    //System.out.println("Searching Windows for instances");
    JFrame mainWindow=null;
    java.awt.Window win[]=java.awt.Window.getWindows();
    for (int i=0; i<win.length; i++) if (win[i] instanceof JFrame) {
      mainWindow=(JFrame) win[i];
      Component c=mainWindow.getContentPane().getComponents()[0];
      if (c instanceof PSurfaceAWT.SmoothCanvas) get(c);
    }
  }
  /**This is used to get the value of fields
   * @return Object value of a field
   * @param j the Object from which the value is taken
   * @param target name of the field
   * @param ref class the field is taken from*/
  public static Object get(Object j, String target, Class<?> ref) {
    try {
      Field f=ref.getDeclaredField(target);
      f.setAccessible(true);
      return f.get(j);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return null;
  }
  /** When using P2D or P3D everything is built differently however there is a weakness to be found in 
    * PSurfaceJOGL as it dispatches a Thread using an annonymous inner class as Runnable*/
  public static void fromThreads() {
    //System.out.println("Searching Threads for instances");
    //This fetches all threads
    Set<Thread> threadSet=Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
    //It iterates upon the threads to find ones dispatched by PSurfaceJOGL
    for (Thread th : threadSet) {
    iteration:
      {
        try {
          //Field f=th.getClass().getDeclaredField("target");
          //f.setAccessible(true);
          Object currinstance=null;
          
          //Here Unsafe is used to breach encapsulation of java.lang
          currinstance=unsafe.getObject(th, fieldIndex);
          if (!currinstance.getClass().toString().contains("PSurfaceJOGL$")) break iteration;
          //System.out.println("Weak spot found! "+th.getName());
          //gets the PSurfaceJOGL
          currinstance=getEnclosingInstance(currinstance);
          //gets the PApplet
          Field f=PSurfaceJOGL.class.getDeclaredField("sketch");
          f.setAccessible(true);
          allFoundPapplets.add((PApplet) (currinstance=f.get(currinstance)));
          //System.out.println("Detection successful");
        }
        catch(Exception e) 
        {
        catchBlock:
          {
            if (e instanceof NoSuchFieldException||e instanceof NullPointerException) {
              //System.err.println("target not found "+th.getName());
              //A NullPointerException may occur
              break catchBlock;
            }
            //System.err.println("Something went wrong!");
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  //This will try to get the enclosing instance of an object (this can also be a lambda)
  public static Object getEnclosingInstance(Object o) {
    //This code will work for Processing 3 (uses annonymous inner classes)
    try {
      Class<?> classused=o.getClass();
      Field this0=classused.getDeclaredField("this$0");
      this0.setAccessible(true);
      return this0.get(o);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      //System.err.println("Can't find enclosing instance of Object, trying to use Lambdas... (To be expected with Processing 4)");
    }
    //This code should work for Processing 4 (lambdas are used instead of inner classes, Lambdas use arg$1 instead this$0) 
    try {
      Class<?> classused=o.getClass();
      Field this0=classused.getDeclaredField("arg$1");
      this0.setAccessible(true);
      return this0.get(o);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      //System.err.println("Detection Failed!");
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Why does this code work?
As mentioned Processing 3 and 4 share two weakpoints. The first is exclusive to JAVA2D and the second exclusive to P2D and P3D:
The JAVA2D weakpoint:
There is a method in java.awt.Window that fetches all active instances of every subclass of itself: `java.awt.Window.getWindows();`
This includes JFrames wich are used by Processing. In fact Processing uses a custom Component of the class PSurfaceAWT.SmoothCanvas that paints all the things done in Processing. From that point one only has to retrieve the enclosing instance and get it's sketch field.
Weakpoint for P2D and P3D
The second Weakpoint lies in PSurfaceJOGL https://github.com/processing/processing4/blob/main/core/src/processing/opengl/PSurfaceJOGL.java#L399-L417
At this point a thread is dispatched using a Runnable implemented via lambda. At line 405 this lambda uses drawException a field of PSurfaceJOGL. In doing so the lambda will hold a reference to its enclosing instance one can access.
But how can we access the Runnable in the first place?
In Java versions below 17 one just could use reflection to do that. However since Java 17 java.lang is encapsulated and Processing doesn't allow adding custom command-line args to open java.lang up!
The answer to this problem is sun.misc.Unsafe
This class doesn't care for encapsulation and can help get the field value.
This does have on ugly side effect though: Using any SecurityManager will blow this class up!
Luckily Processing doesn't have a SecurityManager by default so I can use Unsafe to get the target field from java.lang.Thread. From there I need to grab its enclosing instance and can fetch the sketch field from there!

If it's requested I can post much simpler code (not using Unsafe) (but only works for Processing 3).